# Проблема со сравнением char в С++

Tags: c++

Трабла в том, что ругается на `(path[i] == '\')`. Как это провернуть?Спасибо)
Вот сам код:

```
path = "C:\\*";
int index = path.size() - 1;
for (size_t i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i++)
{

    if (path[i] == '\')
    {
        //Some code;
    }
}
```

Comment: А попробовать `if (path[i] == '\\')` не хотите?

Comment: Ругается, скорее всего, на неизвестную escape-последовательность, то есть сообщение об ошибке более чем содержательно.

Comment: А,понял,спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

`'\\'` - это спецсимвол, вот, посмотрите здесь, например: http://cppstudio.com/post/256/

Комментарии к коду:

1. В строчке  `path = "C:\\*";` полагаю, `path` уже объявлен, например, как `string`, и символ `\` в строке будет один.
2. `for (size_t i = path.size() - 1; i >= 0; i++)` - бесконечный цикл вроде не очень хорошо, проверьте инкремент счетчика.
3. И исправьте условие на `if (path[i] == '\\')` *(см. комментарий @Harry)*

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: 2. Не поможет. Всё равно останется бесконечным.